# RegExp is not getting validated and only consequent check is happening for two small letters

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I have one function in javascript which validates the regular expression and that is not working, please find below my code.

```
var S = jsonData.SYMBOL;
var symbols = new RegExp('[-!$%^&*()_+|~=`{}[:;<>?,.@#\]]{' + S + '}', 'g')
if(psw.value.match(symbols)) {
symbol.classList.remove("invalid");
symbol.classList.add("valid");
} else {
symbol.classList.remove("valid");
symbol.classList.add("invalid");
}
```

In the below code if there are two small letters to be validated then only consequent check is happening but not randomly.
Eg: "aa" is working but 
    "a1a" is not working.

```
  var LC = jsonData.LOWERCASE;
  var lowerCaseLetters = new RegExp('[a-z]{' + LC + '}', 'g')
  if(psw.value.match(lowerCaseLetters)) {
    letter.classList.remove("invalid");
    letter.classList.add("valid");
  } else {
    letter.classList.remove("valid");
    letter.classList.add("invalid");
  }
```

Comment: _How_ is it not working?

Comment: I guess in the second example `LC` is `2`, if that is the case, the regex does exactly what it should do, matches two consecutive lowercase letters. You've misunderstood what `{N}` does in regex.

Comment: @Titus, but I want it to be working if I enter "a1a" also.

Comment: In that case, remove the `{N}` from the regex and the check how many matches there are, something like `cosnt matches = value.matches(/[a-z]/g); if(matches && matches.length == LC) { ... }`

Comment: @Titus, I tried but it is not workig, can you please clarify.

Comment: There is an error in my previous comment, it should be `values.match(..)` instead of `values.matches(..)`. `.match(..)` will return `null` or an array with all the matches, the idea is to check the `length` of this array to see how many matches there are, in the case of `/[a-z]/g` you will see how many lower case letters there are.

Comment: @SebastianSimon, the "new RegExp('[-!$%^&*()_+|~=`{}[:;<>?,.@#\]]{' + S + '}', 'g')" is not validating my html page.

Comment: @Titus, I didn't get you, can you modify my above code and show me, if you don't mind.(for my second example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var S = jsonData.SYMBOL;
var symbols = new RegExp('[-!$%^&*()_+|~=`{}[:;<>?,.@#\\]]{' + S + '}', 'g')
if(psw.value.match(symbols)) {
symbol.classList.remove("invalid");
symbol.classList.add("valid");
} else {
symbol.classList.remove("valid");
symbol.classList.add("invalid");
}
```

The above javascript function is working.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you're looking to check if a string contains a number for specific characters, if that is the case, you could use something like this:

```
var LC = jsonData.LOWERCASE;
var matches = psw.values.match(/[a-z]/g);
if(matches != null && matches.length == LC) {
  letter.classList.remove("invalid");
  letter.classList.add("valid");
} else {
  letter.classList.remove("valid");
  letter.classList.add("invalid");
}
```

You can learn more about `.match(..)` from [HERE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match), in this case (because of the 'g' flag) it will return `null` or an array of substrings (lower case letters) that match the regular expression, this array's `length` will be equal to the total number of lowercase letters in the `psw.values` string.